# UITableView section header creeps under navigation bar

Tags: uinavigationbar, uitableview, translucency, sectionheader

Due to navigation bar style being translucent, I get my first section header (section # 0) hidden under my navigation bar.

I know this has been asked before, and a workaround to it is to do:

```
 self.navController.navigationBar.translucent = YES;
```

This places the problematic view correct - section header appears beneath the navigation bar instead of hiding behind it, which is what I want.

However, this invalidates my other view designs and leaves extra spaces in all of them, right under my nav bar.

How do I get the section header at correct place?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Resolved:

- Open storyboard file
- select UITableView
- Under attribute inspector -> Scroll view size -> Content insets, set Top = 44 (or whichever is your nav bar height).

See image below - it is under size section:

[image]

[And here is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1543875/top-margin-on-uitableviewcontroller) how to fix it programmatically.

Comment: Where is attribute inspector?

Comment: Content insets don't exist in the inspector, only scroll indicators insets.

Comment: @SteveTaylor - check if you accidentally hid it using Hide button.

Comment: I checked again. It's not hidden. It's simply not there. Nevertheless, I resolved this problem not with magic numbers but instead by embedding my `UITableViewController` in a `UINavigationViewController`.

Answer (score 8):

To solve this while using SVPullToRefresh.  I created the method below and inplace of [self.tableView.pullToRefreshView stopAnimating];

```
-(void)stopPullToRefreshAnimation
{
    [self.tableView.pullToRefreshView stopAnimating]; // call to stop animation

    UIEdgeInsets inset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(44, 0, 0, 0);
    self.tableView.contentInset = inset;
    self.tableView.scrollIndicatorInsets = inset;
} //stopPullToRefreshAnimation
```

Comment: property pulltorefreshview not found on object of type tableview

Answer (score 1):

For others having this issue while using (SVPullToRefresh).

It can be solved by changing the view.originalTopInset in UIScrollView+SVPullToRefresh.m to whatever point you want your header to start at.

Comment: Tariq can you please share detail on this? After initial scrolling operation I can never get my first tableview element to be seen it creeps up under the navcontroller/bar. I see in the SVPullToRefresh code the originalTopInset var but it is used in many places - where should I change it and how?

Answer (score 1):

Easiest solution:

```
tableView.tableHeaderView = UIView()
```